# Property 'target' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'. TypeScript React. TS2339

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

The `handleChange()` function is called whenever the input element is changed, but can't seem to access `event.target.value`.

**Error Message**

```
Property 'target' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'.  TS2339
```

**handleChange()**

```
handleChange = (event:HTMLInputElement) => {
    console.log(event);
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({[name]: value});
};
```

**Input Element**

```
<input name='email' type='email' value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} required />
```

Comment: `event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong type on `event`. It's not an `HTMLInputElement`, it's an **event**. For change it's `React.ChangeEvent<T>` where `T` is the type of element you're using it on (`HTMLInputElement` in your case), so:

```
handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    // ...
```